# SSH retain history of machines

Tags: ssh, history

I tend to ssh into alot of machines.

What is the simplest way to recall them ?  For example, is there a command such as

```
ssh --history
```

Which might print something like

```
tuesday april 18 12:00 root@host1.blah.org
tuesday april 18 12:00 jay@github.com
thursday april 18 12:00 root@127.0.0.1
```

One option would be to alias ssh to a wrapper which wrote the commands to a text file but that seems like something I'd have to maintain manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history command to see which commands have been run.

```
history | grep ssh
```

Or, if you're looking for specific times, just search auth.log.

```
grep -E 'ssh.*Accepted' /var/log/auth.log
```

You can get the same info from remote servers with:

```
ssh <server> 'grep -E 'ssh.*Accepted' /var/log/auth.log'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a bash history, then you could try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then write `ssh` (with a space after *ssh*).

Then keep hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until you find the one that you are looking for (search will go backwards, meaning the first result is the more recent in the command history).

### Update

To navigate back and forth in the history, refer to:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39273/how-to-navigate-within-bashs-reverse-search